# Create a pod library based Metal.framework, metal shader reports error: metal_stdlib not found

Tags: cocoapods, shader, metal

I want to create a pod library based Metal.framework. In my .metal files, they include .h header: `#include "ShaderDataTypes.h"`. Then problem comes, when I ***pod lib lint*, it reports below error:

`- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: ShaderDataTypes.h error: 'metal_stdlib' file not found`

Here is my sample project: https://github.com/MrEndlesswhy/DeviceOnlyMetalPod

Hopefully genius on the stackoverflow help me to resolve this issue. I spent several days, but still failed to resolve it.

Many many thanks!

**I Found a soultion**

In `ShaderDataTypes.h`, add below code:

```
#if __METAL_MACOS__ || __METAL_IOS__

#include <metal_stdlib>

using namespace metal;

#endif /* __METAL_MACOS__ || __METAL_IOS__ */
```

Any thing related to `Metal` in your shader .h files, you should use this macos.

Comment: I don't know much about pods but don't you need to tell it to use `Metal.framework` in the `spec.frameworks =` line or something?

Comment: Thank you. I also tried to tell pod to `spec.frameworks = "Metal.framework"`, it was the same. So, I think it's not this issue.